# Blender won't export fbx file with embedded textures

Tags: texturing, export, .fbx

[image]

I currently have a model with a texture and a bump map attached. Bump map is not baked. When I go to export to an .fbx file I do the usual setting path mode to copy and selecting "embed textures" but the exported mesh is plain white.

I assumed the bump map was the issue and disconnected it from the node tree so it was just the texture going to material output but I'm still getting a plain white exported mesh. I also tried creating a completely new material that doesn't use nodes and tried exporting the mesh with that. No use.

I'm not trying to upload to unity or anything. This character is purely for animation. But I'd like the texture embedded for ease of use. I haven't decided if I'll bake or simply re-add the bump map for every animation, but that's not my primary concern right now.

Comment: Use a Principled node, not a Diffuse node. See [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html) for what FBX expects.

Comment: that worked! tysm